logging to check end time, job duration
Typically, in Python / Pandas, we can log various details and metrics such as the start time of a job and the total duration of its execution (end time - start time) using logging module.
Given Spark's distributed architecture, can we obtain similar details for Spark jobs using the logging module?
For instance, if we log the end_time in PySpark using the logging mechanism, does Spark's distributed nature result in multiple end_time being printed for each worker or does it display a single end_time representing the last worker's completion time?

It all depends where and how you log as well as what your code does. However of you're looking for metrics, you'd usually not do anything by yourself but rely on the spark scheduler (Yarn typically) which will give you all such details out of the box and many more.

got it. for example if we log based on just datetime values at the end of code, do we get actual and accurate end time of overall job or for each/any worker?

If I get this right, you'd get only a log on the driver with accurate end time yes.

is this even feasible to log only on driver in spark, given its distributed driver-worker architecture? Much helpful if you can provide as an answer or post any link if available. thank you.

Yes it is. Depending on where the code runs, you'll get logs from that place. If you log outside of any transformations/actions at the end of your code, it'll run in the driver.
